# Time conversion using php

Tags: php, string, time, date-formatting, date-parsing

Is there any way to convert "01:10:00" string into the following format "1 h:10 min" using php? I did this way, but I need to do the opposite.

```
'date('H:i:s',strtotime('1 hour 1 minute 1 second', strtotime('midnight')))'
```

Comment: you can explode it on `:` and then you'll have 01, 10, 00 in an array, then just `echo $array[0]. 'h' ` - is the date static or dynamic?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes, I got it and it works, thank you.But.....This is what I did: '$time= "01:10:00";
$each= explode(":", $time);
echo $each[0] ."h :" . $each[1]. " min";'  // returns 01h :10 min. It's right. The problem is that I didn't want the zeros on right because they aren't required. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're endless ways, e.g.:

```
$input = '01:10:00';
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $input);
$output = "$h h:$m min";
```

You can also tweak output format in different ways, e.g.

```
$output = sprintf("%d h:%02d min", $h, $m);
```

... will display `$h` as integer and `$m` as two-character integer with leading zeroes. It's all just text at this point (don't get confused by the concept of "time").

Comment: This is what I did: '$time= "01:10:00"; $each= explode(":", $time); echo $each[0] ."h :" . $each[1]. " min";' // returns 01h :10 min. It's right. The problem is that I didn't want the zeros on left because they aren't required. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry. Correction: left zeros @Álvaro González

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$time = '01:10:00';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
echo $date->format('H \h:i \m\i\n');
```

Comment: Be careful when using date functions for pure times and durations. `DateTime` cannot store incomplete dates so you'll get default values for all what's missing. This can lead to subtle problems involving time zones and DST, or `25:00` wrapping to `01:00 (in case of durations). I'm not saying it cannot be done, but you need to test your code carefully.